# Choose placeholders for substitution inside a bash script

Tags: bash, sed, glob

**NOTE**: The goal of this question is to find a suitable character sequence for an effective placeholder substitution in a bash script, not finding if a command is evaluated or not.

I have a skeleton named `my_script.skel`of a bash script in which I have to put a placeholder. I want to find a placeholder sequence that can be **safely** substituted (I mean that there aren't any clashes with other bash commands or **other pathological substitutions**, see *A non-safe example* for an example).

I've figured out on my own that enveloping `placeholder_name` within `#~` and `~#` seems a good solution, but I'm not sure that this solution is safe in every possible case.

#### A non-safe example

One can decide to use `/placeholder_name/`. So `my_dumb_script.skel` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
AN_INNOCENT_PATH="/a/simple/placeholder_name/path"
echo /placeholder_name/
```

The **goal** is to replace **only** `/placeholder_name/` in the `echo` command. If now I use sed on the placeholder:

```
sed 's%/placeholder_name/%foobar%g' my_dumb_script.skel > output.bash
```

The output could be unexpected:

```
#!/bin/bash
AN_INNOCENT_PATH="/a/simplefoobarpath"
echo foobar
```

In this case we've obtained an unwanted substitution inside `AN_INNOCENT_PATH`, since it's easy to pattern-match on placeholders that contains the `/` character. I know that it seems very dumb, but you cannot know how people will use your code in the future (and someone could create a folder named `placeholder_name`).

#### A safe example that uses #~

In this case `my_better_script.skel` is the following one:

```
#!/bin/bash
AN_INNOCENT_PATH="/a/simple/placeholder_name/path"
echo #~placeholder_name~#
```

And now we can use `sed`:

```
sed 's%#~placeholder_name~#%foobar%g' my_better_script.skel > output.bash
```

The output now is better:

```
#!/bin/bash
AN_INNOCENT_PATH="/a/simple/placeholder_name/path"
echo foobar
```

Now everything works as intended.

Comment: Can you put a more verifiable input/output with examples? Show us the examples with the output needed, so that we'll know more on the problem you are trying solve.

Comment: Depending on how complex the skeleton script is and how you use it, `sed` might be or might not be the best tool for the goal.

Comment: @axiac I'm open to alternatives to `sed`, but i'd like to remain in the bash-land (i.e. avoid python). If you have any suggestion i'm very happy to receive it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `type` to check if a command will evaluate.

```
$ placeholder1="testing"
$ placeholder2="test"

$ type $placeholder1
-bash: type: testing: not found

$ type $placeholder2
test is a shell builtin
```